# Is it possible to determine if an IE11 window is fully maximized on any of multiple resolution monitors with JS

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

In Chrome I can do this:

```
if (window.innerWidth == window.outerWidth) ...
```

When a Chrome window takes up the entire screen, there are no borders and thus those two values are equal.

---

In Firefox I can do this:

```
if (window.innerWidth == window.screen.width) ...
```

because window.screen.width changes depending on which screen the window is on.

---

There seems to be no perfect solution in IE, as window.screen.width refers only to the primary monitor. The chrome solution won't work either because the innerWidth and outerWidth are the same difference apart regardless of a fully maximized window or not.

Any solution that works with multiple monitors which could all be different resolutions and positions?